# Output after subtracting pointers

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

Basically when I run this as it is it prints 1 and 2.
First of all, ptr2 - ptr should be 4 as I see the pointers pointing to something like this, where each | | represents one byte:

```
|0|0|0|0| 0|0|1|0|
ptr..........ptr2
```

When we subtract pointers we subtract the addresses they point to, right? So I would expect 4 to be printed and then 2, since the memory has been allocated continuously.

Of course this is not the actual output. So where is my thinking incorrect?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int *ptr;
    ptr = (int *)malloc(2*sizeof(int));

    int *ptr2;

    ptr2 = &ptr[1];

    printf("%d\n", ptr2 - ptr);

    ptr[1] = 2;
    printf("%d", ptr2[0]);

    free(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get `1` and `2` that's expected. You may want to parenthesise here `ptr2 = &(ptr[1]);` to avoid precedence issues. But it works. What's your output?

Comment: oh: pointer arithmetic...

Comment: I am also getting 1 and 2 but theoretically I think it should be 4 and 2 as explained above

Comment: this is a duplicate, there's no doubt

Comment: Pointers have a type: subtracting pointers gives you the distance between them *in terms of that type*. Since these are int pointers, the "1" is telling you that those pointers are 1 int apart, which is probably 4 bytes on most platforms. Maybe 8.

Comment: How does the result you **get** contradict what your C book states about pointer arithmetic?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: Okay, I get it. But what if they have different datatypes?

Comment: blaaaatant dupe ... of dupe of dupe of dupe...

Comment: If they have different data types, the compiler won't let you subtract them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you subtract two pointers, the result is not difference between the numerical values but the difference in the number of *elements*.

Since `ptr` points to the first element of an array and `ptr2` points to the second element, there is a one element difference between the two, and that is the result.

Section 6.5.6 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding Additive Operators states the following:

> *9* When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array
>   object; **the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two
>   array elements.**

If you want to see the byte difference between the addresses, you can cast the pointers to `char *`:

```
char *p1 = (char *)ptr;
char *p2 = (char *)ptr2;
printf("%td\n", p2 - p1);
```

Comment: But I am allocating memory worth 8 bytes. ptr2 should point to index 4, right? There is a 4 byte difference between index 4 and index 0.

Comment: @CodeChef123  The byte index is irrelevant.  Even though the pointers may in fact be 4 bytes apart, if an `int` is 4 bytes in size that means that the pointers are 1 `int` apart, which is what the result is.  If you had casted those pointers to `char *`, then you would see a different results because a `char` is a different size from an `int`.